# Best way to joint list of list horizontly

Tags: python, list

For example, I have this:

```
list_of_lists = [
            [[1,2,3],       [4,5,6],       [7,8,9]      ],
            [[11,22,33],    [44,55,66],    [77,88,99]   ],
            [[111,222,333], [444,555,666], [777,888,999]],         
        ]
```

How to get this the best way:

```
expected_result =  [
            [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
            [11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99],
            [111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999]         
        ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not too hard to do with a pair of nested list comprehensions:

```
result = [[x for inner in middle for x in inner] for middle in list_of_lists]
```

Answer (score 3):

Best way is to use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) with a list comprehension:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> [list(chain.from_iterable(x)) for x in list_of_lists]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99], [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999]]
```

Or if NumPy is an option:

```
In [47]: arr = np.array(list_of_lists)                                  

In [48]: a, b, c = arr.shape                                            

In [49]: arr.flatten().reshape(a, b*c)                                  
Out[49]: 
array([[  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9],
       [ 11,  22,  33,  44,  55,  66,  77,  88,  99],                   
       [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [operator.concat:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.concat)

```
list_of_lists = [
            [[1,2,3],       [4,5,6],       [7,8,9]      ],
            [[11,22,33],    [44,55,66],    [77,88,99]   ],
            [[111,222,333], [444,555,666], [777,888,999]],         
        ]

import operator
expected_result = [reduce(operator.concat, List) for List in list_of_lists)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way

```
expected_result1 = list(map(lambda row: sum(row, []), list_of_lists))

print(expected_result)
print(expected_result1)

The output is:
#[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99], [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999]]
#[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99], [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999]]
```

Comment: This will be very slow for longer lists because of the quadratic `sum`.